# React state, setState with const

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Mostly I have seen in documentation and others code they wrote set hook like this picture in documentation:

[image]

in it they are changing **count** value by calling setCount.
My question is that since count is declared with **const** keyword how is it changing on every setCount?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On re-renders, you are getting a new variable. `setCount` changes the value internally and ties the change into the life-cycle of the component. When a render occurs, you get a new `count` variable entirely, which is different than doing `count = 9`. Remember, components are just functions that are being called. Like any other function, each time you call it, you get a whole new set of variables scoped to it.

`useState` is returning an array with a value and a function, `[9, () => {}]`. All `const [count, setCount]` is doing is destructuring that array.

Comment: Thankyou I got this now 

Comment: @MidhaTahir glad I could help.